# How does SQL Server store decimal type values internally?

Tags: sql-server, storage, numeric, internals

In SQL Server you can use `FLOAT` or `REAL` to store floating point values the storage format of which is cleared defined by the IEEE 754 standard. For fixed point values we can use `DECIMAL` type (which has a synonym `NUMERIC`). However I'm not pretty sure how SQL Server store `DECIMAL` values internally. For example, if I define a table and insert a row like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.test_number_types') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.test_number_types;
CREATE TABLE dbo.test_number_types
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    c1 NUMERIC(5, 4)
)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.test_number_types(c1)VALUES(5.7456);
```

When I use `DBCC PAGE` command to check how SQL Server stores the number 5.7456, I got this:

```
01 70 E0 00 00
```

This hex string should use little endian. I can't figure out how SQL Server turns 5.7456 into `01 70 E0 00 00` and how it decides how many bytes are for the integral part and how many bytes are for the decimal parts. Can anyone help?

---

BTW, I've checked the book "SQL Server 2012 Internals". There is a chapter dedicated to data type storage. But it seems `DECIMAL` type storage is not mentioned in the book.

Comment: Hint:  BCD, binary-coded decimal (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal).  I can't swear this is how SQL Server actually stores the value, but it is a very typical method for storing fixed point values in other languages.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for the link. I'll take a look.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried, seems not BCD encoding.

Comment: `57456` = `0xE070`

Comment: SQL Server doesn't use BCD.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Martin's Smith comment gives you the clue. SQL Server does not use BCD.
It stores the data as a whole number, without the decimal place (which it can do because the decimal place is stored in the metadata for the column). So `5.7456` is stored as `57456`, or `0xE070`. After SQL's infamous byte swapping this is transformed to `70 E0 00 00`.

The leading `01` is the sign. `01` is used for positive numbers; `00` for negatives.

(However, I must ask - why do you need this? In typical use, you should never need to bother with SQL Server's internals)

Comment: Thanks again Hugo! I want to know this is because I'm reading the book "SQL Server 2012 Internals" and I found DECIMAL type is not mentioned. Just out of curiosity.

Comment: I used `DECLARE @value NUMERIC(5,4) = 5.7456;SELECT CAST(@value AS varbinary);` and I got `0x0504000170E00000` what I don't understand is the meaning of captive and trailing zeros, I would appreciate if this is explained.

Comment: @lvanzinho: Most of this is already explained. A short recap plus some additional to fill in the blanks: `5.7456` is represented as whole number `57456`, in hex `0xE070`. It uses four bytes to leading trailing zeroes are added for `0x0000E070`, then the bytes are swapped for `0x70E00000`. That is the second half of the result you see.
The first half is simply a representation of length (`05`), mantissa (`04`), two bytes either unused or undocumented status stuff, and finally the sign (`00` for negative or `01` for positive).

Comment: "SQL's infamous byte swapping" - interesting!!! Any references about how & why this is done would be appreciated.

Comment: @ReversedEngineer - The official term is "little endian", and you can find a wealth of information here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness
As for "why", I don't think there is an official source but the Wikipedia article states that "The Intel x86 and AMD64 / x86-64 series of processors use the little-endian format". Most of SQL Server's history, these were the CPUs used on the large majority of its installations, so it makes sense that the internal storage is aligned with what the CPU handles natively, to reduce performance overhead.