# How SQL Server store/transfer decimal stream

Tags: c#, sql-server, decimal, protocols

I'm working on MS-TDS protocol, what I'm trying todo is to read/write TDS stream, and get/set a `System.Data.DataTable` from/to it.
I got all C# types working already, except `decimal` `varchar(max)` `varbinary(max)` columns

in C#, I got following results for `12345678912345678912.3456789m` and `1234567891234567891.23456789m`

```
var bits = decimal.GetBits(12345678912345678912.3456789m)
using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
    foreach (var b in bits)
        ms.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(b), 0, 4);
    var decimalBytes = ms.ToArray();
}
```

```
 10 15 5F 04 7C 9F B1 E3 F2 FD 1E 66 00 00 00 07 00
 10 15 5F 04 7C 9F B1 E3 F2 FD 1E 66 00 00 00 08 00
```

these totally make sense to me, the last byte is decimal size(position), which is 7 and 8, the value part is the same. but in sql, they look completely different:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(12345678912345678912.3456789 AS decimal(38,15)) AS varbinary)
SELECT CAST(CAST(1234567891234567891.23456789 AS decimal(38,15)) AS varbinary)
results:
0x260F 0001 0075 AA3F 0AF2 2A3A DB18 0560 B060 0200
0x260F 0001 80D8 5D06 01E5 9D52 7C82 0070 DE3C 0000
```

and in TDS stream `DataType=[0x6A,0x11,0x26,0x0F] decimal(38,15)`, sql server returns this:

```
0x81, // token "COLMETADATA"
0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 3 columns

0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, // usertype = 0, falgs = 9
0xa7, 0xff, 0xff, 0x09, 0x04, 0xd0, 0x00, 0x34, // 0xA7=BIGVARCHRTYPE  0xffff=MAX, 
0x0e, 0x56, 0x00, 0x41, 0x00, 0x52, 0x00, 0x43, 0x00, 0x48, 0x00, 0x41, 0x00, 0x52, 0x00, 0x4d, 0x00, 0x41, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x5f, 0x00, 0x43, 0x00, 0x6f, 0x00, 0x6c, 0x00, // unicode "VARCHARMAX_Col"

0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, // usertype = 0, falgs = 9
0x6a, 0x11, 0x26, 0x0f, // 0x6A=DECIMAL  0x11=Size, precision = (38,15)
0x0b, 0x44, 0x00, 0x45, 0x00, 0x43, 0x00, 0x49, 0x00, 0x4d, 0x00, 0x41, 0x00, 0x4c, 0x00, 0x5f, 0x00, 0x43, 0x00, 0x6f, 0x00, 0x6c, 0x00, // unicode "DECIMAL_Col"

0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, // usertype = 0, falgs = 9
0xa5, 0xff, 0xff, // 0xA5=BIGVARBINTYPE 0xffff=MAX
0x0d, 0x56, 0x00, 0x41, 0x00, 0x52, 0x00, 0x42, 0x00, 0x49, 0x00, 0x4e, 0x00, 0x4d, 0x00, 0x41, 0x00, 0x58, 0x00, 0x5f, 0x00, 0x43, 0x00, 0x6f, 0x00, 0x6c, 0x00, // unicode "VARBINMAX_Col"

0xd1, // token "ROW"
0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x42, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // varchar(max) value, how to read this ?
0x11, 0x01, 0x00, 0x92, 0xa8, 0x7c, 0x7e, 0xe4, 0x25, 0x1a, 0x0e, 0xab, 0x6b, 0x4d, 0x82, 0x84, 0x04, 0x00, // decimal value, how to read this ?
0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x62, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // varbinary(max) value, how to read this ?

0xd1, // token "ROW"
0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x43, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x11, 0x01, 0x00, 0x75, 0xaa, 0x3f, 0xa6, 0x63, 0x9d, 0x02, 0x1b, 0x91, 0x57, 0xa1, 0xa6, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00,
0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x63, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,

0xd2,  // token "NBCROW"
0x05,  // NullBitmap 00000101:  1st and 3rd columns are null
0x11, 0x01, 0x50, 0x24, 0xc2, 0x2a, 0xf2, 0x77, 0xd5, 0x97, 0x0f, 0x03, 0xee, 0xf5, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
```

decimal value in the 1st row is

```
0x11, 0x01, 0x00, 0x92, 0xa8, 0x7c, 0x7e, 0xe4, 0x25, 0x1a, 0x0e, 0xab, 0x6b, 0x4d, 0x82, 0x84, 0x04, 0x00,
```

`0x11` should be length, `0x01` means positive value (from this post [How does SQL Server store decimal type values internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41205138/how-does-sql-server-store-decimal-type-values-internally?answertab=active#tab-top))
 Question: how can I resolving these bytes to a decimal value?  and how should I write  `varchar(max)` `varbinary(max)` value to TDS `ROW TokenStream`?  Any help is appreciated

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: If you take your value and write to the database, then read it back out, it's the same value right? i.e. if you wrote a decimal to the db, read it back out, and then used `decimal.getbits`, it'd be the same value.  Where does `cast AS varbinary` come into this?

Comment: You could just check the source code. [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient) is available on Github. I think you need [TdsParser](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/TdsParser.cs) and [TdsParserStateObject](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/TdsParserStateObject.cs)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid no, they are not the same, the last int32 of `decimal.getbits` must have `0` on 0~15 and 21~30 bits, data in tds stream they are not

Comment: You're saying if you write a value to the database from C# then read it back in from C#... it's a different value?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I'm saying bits in tds stream are differernt than decimal.getbits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. the difference is `TDS stream` use the first byte as sign and use fixed Decimal point, `decimal.GetBits` use few bits in last byte as sign and Decimal point

```
// write decimal to TDS stream
static byte[] DecimalBytes(decimal dec, int precision = 15)
{
    var round = decimal.Round(dec, precision);
    var valueToWrite = round;
    var sign = round < 0 ? (byte)0x00 : (byte)0x01;
    // get the string
    var str = round.ToString();
    // string without Decimal point
    var numbers = str.Replace(".", string.Empty);
    var dotIdx = str.IndexOf('.');
    if (dotIdx > 0)
    {
        // there must be {precision} digits on the right side of "."
        var padding = precision - (numbers.Length - dotIdx);
        // padding numbers with '0' to precision length
        numbers = numbers.PadRight(numbers.Length + padding, '0');
    }
    else
    {
        numbers = numbers.PadRight(numbers.Length + precision, '0');
    }
    if (!decimal.TryParse(numbers, out valueToWrite))
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Invalid decimal value for Database Type decimal(38,{precision})");
    }
    using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        var bits = decimal.GetBits(valueToWrite);
        ms.WriteByte(0x0D); // length=13
        ms.WriteByte(sign);
        ms.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(bits[0]), 0, 4);
        ms.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(bits[1]), 0, 4);
        ms.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(bits[2]), 0, 4);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pleased you found an answer and posted it here to help others. I'm still puzzled about the question. But I don't see any SQL code here at all so I guess it was a C# thing

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid it is C# thing, basically it's a TcpLisitener, to write TDS stream to `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter`